# Encountered error while building for device - flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, build

Encountered error while building for device for iOS in flutter, I have tried many things but no resolution yet. This issue is occurring with flutter firebase project and the release is stuck for more than 4 days. please guide me to resolve this issue as soon as possible

```
> Error output from Xcode build: ↳
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h"
> is a member of
>     multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
> membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but
>     membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a
> member of multiple
>     groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but
>     membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h"
> is a member of
>     multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
> membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but
>     membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a
> member of multiple
>     groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but
>     membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h"
> is a member of multiple groups
>     ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but membership in
>     targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
> path.
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is
> a member of multiple groups
>     ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but membership in
>     targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
> path.
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member
> of multiple groups
>     ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but membership in
>     targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
> path.
>     2020-09-04 19:28:49.310 xcodebuild[12210:62950] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h"
> is a member
>     of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
> membership in one of the groups will be preserved
>     (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
>     ** BUILD FAILED **
> 
> 
> Xcode's output: ↳
>     In file included from /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
>     command [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param sharedStyle
>      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
>     command [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param allowTapToDismiss
>      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found
>     in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param allowTapToDismiss
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
>      @param allowTapToDismiss
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>             tapToDismissEnabled
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
>     command [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param queueEnabled
>      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:20:23:
> warning: unused variable 'viewController'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>         UIViewController *viewController =
>                           ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:99:21:
> warning: unused variable 'topPadding'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>                 CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
>                         ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:100:21:
> warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>                 CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
>                         ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:73:19:
> warning: unused variable 'size'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>             NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
>                       ^
>     8 warnings generated.
>     In file included from /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
>     command [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param sharedStyle
>      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
>     command [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param allowTapToDismiss
>      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found
>     in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param allowTapToDismiss
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
>      @param allowTapToDismiss
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>             tapToDismissEnabled
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
>     command [-Wdocumentation]
>      @param queueEnabled
>      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:20:23:
> warning: unused variable 'viewController'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>         UIViewController *viewController =
>                           ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:99:21:
> warning: unused variable 'topPadding'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>                 CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
>                         ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:100:21:
> warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>                 CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
>                         ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:73:19:
> warning: unused variable 'size'
>     [-Wunused-variable]
>             NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
>                       ^
>     8 warnings generated.
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:195:43:
> warning:
>     'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling.
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>     - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage
> *)remoteMessage {
>                                               ^
>     In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:219:1:
> note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly
>     marked deprecated here
>     __deprecated_msg(
>     ^
>     In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
>     In module 'Foundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
>     In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
>     :6:
>     In module 'Darwin' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
>     dation.h:16:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:191:48:
> note: expanded from macro
>     '__deprecated_msg'
>             #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
>                                                           ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:307:24:
> warning:
>     'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling.
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>         didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
>                            ^
>     In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:219:1:
> note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly
>     marked deprecated here
>     __deprecated_msg(
>     ^
>     In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
>     In module 'Foundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
>     In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
>     :6:
>     In module 'Darwin' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
>     dation.h:16:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:191:48:
> note: expanded from macro
>     '__deprecated_msg'
>             #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
>                                                           ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:141:30:
> warning:
>     'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message
> delivery. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>         [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
>                                  ^
>     In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:283:56:
> note: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' has been
>     explicitly marked deprecated here
>     @property(nonatomic) BOOL shouldEstablishDirectChannel DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
>                                                            ^
>     In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
>     In module 'Foundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
>     In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
>     :6:
>     In module 'Darwin' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
>     dation.h:16:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:182:64:
> note: expanded from macro
>     'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
>                 #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
>                                                                    ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:196:52:
> warning: 'appData' is
>     deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>       [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
>                                                        ^
>     In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62:
> note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated
>     here
>     @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
>                                                                  ^
>     In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
>     In module 'Foundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
>     In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
>     :6:
>     In module 'Darwin' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
>     dation.h:16:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:60:
> note: expanded from macro
>     'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
>             #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
>                                                                ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:306:1:
> warning: implementing
>     deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
>     - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
>     ^
>     In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:253:1:
> note: method 'messaging:didReceiveMessage:' declared
>     here
>     - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
>     ^
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:308:63:
> warning: 'appData' is
>     deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>       [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
>                                                                   ^
>     In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62:
> note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated
>     here
>     @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
>                                                                  ^
>     In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
>     In module 'Foundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
>     In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
>     :6:
>     In module 'Darwin' imported from
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
>     dation.h:16:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:60:
> note: expanded from macro
>     'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
>             #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
>                                                                ^
>     6 warnings generated.
>     6 warnings generated.
>     1 warning generated.
>     Failed to subset font; aborting.
> 
> 
>     Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
>     note: Using new build system
>     note: Building targets in parallel
>     note: Planning build
>     note: Constructing build description
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController'
>     from project 'Pods')
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
>     'Pods')
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from
>     project 'Pods')
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
>     'Pods')
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
>     'Pods')
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
>     'Pods')
>     warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
>     /Users/jimmy/Documents/firebaseproject/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h
> (in target
>     'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
> 
> Encountered error while building for device.
```

Comment: Have you done flutter update? Which version have you?

Comment: @Hakiza Flutter version 1.20.3, dart version 2.9.2, yes I did the flutter update

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, then please share it.

Answer (score 9):

[Jimmy Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14185798/jimmy-anderson) after running `flutter upgrade`, with the existing project you need to check the `dependencies` used if they are up to date too.

I had the same error with `version 1.20.1` and the solution was to delete the `Pods` folder, the `pubspec.lock` file:

): Clean completely all points to links:

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
```

): Finally run these:

```
rm ios/Podfile
rm pubspec.lock
flutter run
```

If anyone has an up-to-date answer can complete this temporary solution.

Answer (score 4):

These steps helped me to resolve a similar issue

1. At first try to take an Android build by following these steps

- Delete `pubspec.lock` file
- `flutter clean` ( inside ur project directory )
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter build apk --release`

I then saw my Android build fail, it was some dependency related issues and I fixed those. Then repeated the above step 1. After that my Android build was successful.

2. Then try to take the iOS build by following these steps

- Deleted `Pods` folder inside the `ios` directory
- Deleted the `Podfile.lock` file inside the `ios` directory
- `cd ios`
- `pod install`
- `pod update`
- `cd ..`
- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter build ios --release`

And then my iOS build was successfull

Answer (score 0):

**Those steps worked for me:**

1. Run `flutter build`
2. Open Xcode (Runner.xcworkspace)
3. Go to Product -> Clean Build Folder
4. Run on a real Device
5. Then try again - `flutter build ios`